# Does it makes sense to use const qualifier on input parameters for C++ functions?

Tags: c++

Does it makes sense to use the `const` qualifier for input parameters in `C++` when the parameter is passed by value ?

For example if I pass a primitive type like `integer`:

```
void function( const int aValue );
```

does it gain any benefit over the same function without using the `const`:

```
void function( int aValue );
```

Is there any difference if I pass my own data type ?

```
void function( Data aData );
void function( const Data aData );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the function body cannot modify the parameter. So it does give you a little more program stability.

The same rule applies for your own classes, although you might want to pass those by const reference if a value copy is expensive.

Some houses insist on the style: `const` unless non-const is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are passing by value `const` does nothing for you in this case in terms of stopping you from modifying the original object.  It does stop you from modifying the copy in the function though.